# Is there any way to capture audio through tinymix commands?

Tags: android, audio, android-4.4-kitkat, alsa, tinyalsa

I am trying to capture Raw Audio data directly through USB from mobile so is there any tinymix commands to capture it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First record the audio using tinycap 
   `$ adb shell tinycap <dest-file-path>`
2. Pull the recorded file to host over USB 
    
   `$ adb pull`

Comment: Is `tinycap` still works on android 11 in 2021?

Comment: I think only on rooted devices. Tried on the emulator- didn't work